# Как остановить смену слайдов при переключении на другую вкладку?

Tags: javascript, jquery

На сайте есть слайдер:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $('header .slider div:nth-child('+slide_number+')').css('opacity','0');

    slide_number++;
    if (slide_number == 5) {
        slide_number = 1;
    }

    $('header .slider div:nth-child('+slide_number+')').css('opacity','1');     
}, 5000);
```

Если перейти на другую вкладку браузера, а через некоторое время вернуться,
то слайды начинают листаться очень быстро, а затем все приходит в норму.

Можно ли при переходе на другую вкладку отключить листание слайдов,
а при возвращении опять включить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

События onblur и onfocus не подойдут?

Вот собственно похожий [вопрос.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6979239/determine-if-browser-tab-is-active-ie)

И там же [ответ.](http://www.thefutureoftheweb.com/demo/2007-05-16-detect-browser-window-focus/)

Answer (score 0):

Советую использовать mouseleave / mouseenter так как при onblur и onfocus при возврате на закладку фокус не происходит автоматически, а только после нажатия на элемент.

В моем случае это вот такой код на jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).mouseenter(function () {
        if(!myVar){//проверяем запущен ли таймер
            myVar = setInterval(function(){ next(); }, 15000);
        }
    });
jQuery(document).mouseleave(function () {clearInterval(myVar);});
```